# How to allow a table to occupy the whole available canvas width?

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I'm using asciidoctor with html5 backend.

Is it possible to allow a particular [table](https://asciidoc.org/newtables.html) to occupy the whole available canvas width, instead of obeying the document's width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to customize the CSS to achieve that.

See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66651861/4023764) for the strategy to accomplish this.