# Asciidoc: How to create clickable anchors for anchors

Tags: html, css, jekyll, asciidoc, asciidoctor

I have a jekyll blog site using asciidoc. Now I want an "anchor" symbol to appear when hovering over a heading, like on GitHub:

[image: GitHub heading hover]

When clicking the symbol, the browser should jump to the heading, so the HTML output should look like this:

```html
<h2 id="whats-in-a-rainbow-table">
    <a href="#whats-in-a-rainbow-table"></a>
    What's in a Rainbow table?
</h2>
```

The equivalent asciidoc markup is:

```
== xref:whats-in-a-rainbow-table[ ]What's in a Rainbow table?
```

This works and looks good with some CSS, but I don't want to write this much markup for every heading. Is there a way to automate this?

Comment: Honestly I am not really firm with asciidoc. But as I know/remember it is possible to connect asciidoc somehow with JS? So that could be a typical purpose you could solve with JS ... are you able to do it in JS?

Comment: @Brebber I guess that only works with the JS version of Asciidoc, I'm using the Ruby version (because Jekyll uses Ruby). Unfortunately I'm not very familiar with Ruby.

Comment: I saw a tutorial to write Asciidoc macros in Ruby. I might actually do that, to reduce the amount of boilerplate per heading, but I was hoping that there's a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the "permalink" icon would best be done with custom JavaScript, added to the theme used to generate HTML.

You can add custom JavaScript using a "docinfo" file. See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66665245/4023764) for the strategy to do so.

Your custom JavaScript should run on page load, search for all headings, create the permalink anchor, and inject it into the heading markup.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of this, this is a much more elegant solution. Thanks!